# How to make StatefulJobs run consecutively (not concurrently)?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a `scheduler`:

```
                SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory("quartz.properties");
                sched = schedFact.getScheduler();
                sched.start();
                JobDetail jobDetail;
                CronTrigger trigger;
                for (ReportDetails report : reports) {
                    jobDetail = new JobDetail(report.getName() + _REPORT, GRP, ReportJob.class);
                    jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put(ReportJob.DATA_REPORT, report);
                    sched.addJob(jobDetail, true);
                    if (report.getCronExp() != null && report.getCronExp().length() > 0) {
                        trigger = new CronTrigger(report.getName() + _TRIGGER, GRP);
                        trigger.setCronExpression(report.getCronExp());
                        trigger.setJobGroup(GRP);
                        trigger.setJobName(report.getName() + _REPORT);
                        sched.scheduleJob(trigger);
                    }
                }
```

And there is my `job` instance:

```
public class ReportJob implements StatefulJob {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ReportJob.class);
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        ReportDetails report = (ReportDetails) context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().get(DATA_REPORT);
        report.getLogger().info("job for report started");
        ...
        report.getLogger().info("Job for report ended");
    }
}
```

The thing is that though ReportJob implements StatefulJob indeed jobs run concurrently.

> QuartzScheduler_Worker-1 | job for report started
>
> QuartzScheduler_Worker-2 | job for report started
>
> QuartzScheduler_Worker-2 | job for report ended
>
> QuartzScheduler_Worker-1 | job for report ended

I want them to run consecutively, one by one. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood my error: `StatefulJob` prevents multiple instances of a job WITH THE SAME KEY from running at the same time. While I'd created the jobs with different keys.